# Springboot cache auto refreshing with redis and apache ignite

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, ignite

I am working with java spring boot application and also currently I am using Redis for caching.

Now I have a requirement like, I need to refresh the cache by each day.

As an initial level, I am manually flushing the cache of the redis daily.

Is there any configuration to automate it? or what will be the best practice to handle the same?

I am ready to switch to any alternative like apache ignite.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to me, you can try the following.
In spring boot you can write cron as below.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/30 * * * ?")              // execure after every 30 min
public void clearCacheSchedule(){
    // write the code to clear the cache.
}
```

Comment: Thank You. Is this is the recommended way?

Answer (score 0):

With Ignite you can set up [expiration policies](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/expiry-policies) for the whole cache or individual entries.